# Helm hook for during deletion

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Usecase I have:
When deleting/uninstalling helm chart If the complete deletion doesn't end in X minutes I want to run a custom script.

Helm has these kind of hooks:
https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/

```
pre-delete  Executes on a deletion request before any resources are deleted from Kubernetes
post-delete Executes on a deletion request after all of the release's resources have been deleted
```

None of them is suitable for my use-case , the first runs immediatly before any deletion , the second one run only after the deletion succeeded.

Comment: Hello @beatrice. Have you considered running something like this: `helm uninstall RELEASE_NAME --timeout=5m || custom_script`?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor
I dont want it to timeout. The helm uninstall should keep running.
My specific use case: 
someone else launch 'helm uninstall --timeout=5m'
Sometimes my pod stuck in terminating state for more than 5m, so timing out.
The one who launched the helm uninstall don't want to see the timing out at all.
So I have to solve this inside the chart. 
The real reason behind this issue is in investigation. Until then I just want to run a forced helm deletion from a script if the deletion doesn't finish in ~1-2min